# NSPredicate with relationships

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nspredicate

I'm trying to filter the result for my table list that shows Employees. One filter should show every Employee that belongs to a certain Company (based on the name of the company).

In Core Data, the entity Company has a To-Many Relationship to the entity Employee.

```
_fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[_fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Employee" inManagedObjectContext:_moc]];

NSPredicate *employeeNamePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name != %@",@"Bob"];
NSPredicate *employeeCompanyNamePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"company.name == %@",companyName];

NSArray *filters = @[employeeNamePredicate, employeeCompanyNamePredicate];

NSPredicate *compoundPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:filters];

[_fetchRequest setPredicate:compoundPredicate];

NSError *error = nil;
_filteredResult = [_moc executeFetchRequest:_fetchRequest error:&error];
```

But nothing really happens. @"company.name" doesn't seem to work as expected. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I can see no obvious error in your code. Do you get no results at all or wrong results? Can you show the NSLog output of compoundPredicate?

Comment: Oh I had made a stupid mistake...The code works fine. I should've Unit Tested this... Thanks!